# XML file to SQL

Tags: php, database

How can I parse an xml string `<description>content</description>` and move the content into my database with PHP7?

Example:

**Database Structure**:

```
ID;
NAME;
DESCRIPTION;
```

**XML**:

```
<thing>
<id>1</id>
<name>aaa</name>
<description>something</description>
ecc...
</thing>
```

So, let's pretend we modified every column for mistake but we have saved everything in a XML file, but the SQL is very big to modify manually, so we could do what I explained before. How could I accomplish this? Thanks in advance, and sorry if this question is very strange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML data using php to put into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161722/parsing-xml-data-using-php-to-put-into-mysql-database)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you use a CSV file as database? Please provide more infos about the XML structure or post a better example.

Comment: I did just an example at the moment to show you more details. I didn't know how to explain, because is a long process.